# How to cache an array of Images fetched from firebase Storage using SDWebImage in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, caching, firebase-storage, sdwebimage

I am fetching images from firebase storage in the form of data and I want to cache the images in my app using SDWebImage. Please guide me how to achieve it?

```
 for x in images_list{

                let storageRef = storage.child("images/\(x).jpg")
                storageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
                    if let error = error{
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    }
                    else{
                        imagesarray.append(UIImage(data: data!)!)
                    }
                    if let x = images_list.last{
                                cell.imageDemo.animationImages = imagesarray
                                cell.imageDemo.sd_setImage(with: storageRef) // Here I Want to cache the images of **imagesarray** that are being animated
                                cell.imageDemo.animationDuration = 2
                                cell.imageDemo.startAnimating()

                    }
                }


            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are downloading imageData directly from firebase in your question. Instead of using `getData` you will need to use `downloadURL` method. Like this:

```
for x in image_list {

        let storageRef = storage.child("images/\(x).jpg")

        //then instead of downloading data download the corresponding URL
        storageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
            if let error = error {

            } else {

                //make your imageArray to hold URL rather then images directly
                imagesArray.append(url)
            }
        }

    }

    //////This is were you would use those url////////
    let url = imageArray.first!
    imageView.sd_setImage(with: url, completed: nil)
```

The most important part here is download url rather than image data. And whenever you set the image url to the imageView the SDWebImage library will cache it and display if already cached

Comment: Thanks for helping, but i still can't understand how to cache an array of images. I thought of a solution and can you please suggest is it right or not?

Comment: for x in images_list{
            let storageRef = storage.child("images/\(x).jpg")
            storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                if let error = error{
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                else{
                    imagesarray.append(url!)
                }
                if let x = images_list.last{
                    cell.imageDemo.sd_setAnimationImages(with: imagesarray)
//                    cell.imageDemo.sd_
                }
            }
        }

Comment: your code should work, once you set the image to UIImageView using this library it should automatically download and cache the images. So the next time it will load faster. You can check this by going into the Documents directory of your device/simulator. There should be whole bunch of cached files for your images

Comment: thanks for the replying bro, it was really helpful, the images are getting loaded and animated but it gets displayed very fast. I need to change the duration of animation now

Comment: you could set `imageView.animationDuration` with your desired value

Comment: That method is just helper to set Array of images to `UIImageView` so that it can be animated. It should work the same. You should try it :)

Comment: It completely works bro. I forgot to imageView.startAnimating()

Comment: I've tested it with this piece of code. It is working fine:  `let imagesURL = ["http://dummyimage.com/225x184.jpg/ff4444/ffffff","http://dummyimage.com/171x194.png/cc0000/ffffff","http://dummyimage.com/196x144.png/5fa2dd/ffffff","http://dummyimage.com/147x191.bmp/cc0000/ffffff"].compactMap { URL(string: $0) }
        
        imageView.sd_setAnimationImages(with: imagesURL)
        imageView.animationDuration = TimeInterval(2.0)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getData method, I used downloadURL method and Cached the array of images.

```
var imagesarray = [URL]()
for x in images_list{
        let storageRef = storage.child("images/\(x).jpg")
        storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            if let error = error{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            else{
                imagesarray.append(url!)
            }
            if let x = images_list.last{
                cell.imageDemo.sd_setAnimationImages(with: imagesarray)
                cell.imageDemo.animationDuration = 2
                cell.imageDemo.startAnimating()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This should work fine. With animation delayed between images by 2.

Comment: Thanks for helping bro. It helped a lot